# Oxyplot: Start ColumnSeries at value

Tags: c#, plot, oxyplot

I have two x axes on an Oxyplot plot model: a category axis for a column series and a linear axis for a line series.  I have a line series plotted on the linear axis and would like to offset the column series so that, instead of starting at 0, the first column appears at value 100 on the linear axis.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

*ColumnSeries* has a property called *BaseValue* which can be used to start the column at the point you want. As you might have guessed it defaults to 0.

Comment: This sounds correct but I no longer have access to Visual Studio to verify.  I'll accept as solution if others can confirm or if you can post an image showing your solution.

Comment: Well, if you check the source code in [BarSeriesBase](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/Series/BarSeries/BarSeriesBase.cs#L269) you will see it being used in Render to call this.GetRectangle and then in the implementation of GetRectangle in [ColumnSeries](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/Series/BarSeries/ColumnSeries.cs#L124) you can see it uses it to draw the actual rectangle. This is how I actually figured this was the property to use.